# How to play sound till the user hits a key?

Tags: python, tkinter

First thought of implementing this using threads but python doesnt have a way for killing threads. I have read the other topic on killing threads.
Is there any proper platform independent way of doing this?

Comment: You have to specify the target platform, in the least. (And the kind of sound API...)

Comment: Platform: Windows. I am using bell() in tk for playing the sound. I want to repeat the sound till the user hits a key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd better use a Tk timer for ringing periodically, and then stop it when you get the key press.

See http://www.java2s.com/Code/Python/GUI-Tk/Clockevent.htm for an example how to use timer.

Thus you will avoid creating another thread.

Comment: Is it possible to stop the timer after getting a keypress? http://python.active-venture.com/lib/timer-objects.html - Here I find  that you can stop the timer only before the action starts.

Comment: @dante: you can just not reactivate it. (not call .after)

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific? This could be done in pygame, but you'd need to open a graphical window.